# Trying to remove the default keyboard language

Tags: windows, keyboard, language

I try to remove Romanian Legagy language from my keyboard languages list (it is the default language) and I can't do it.

It is strange that it appears in English category. If I try to remove English from there, it works, but Romanian Legacy...

I attache some pictures to be more specific.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making a different language/keyboard layout the default first? Windows almost never lets you delete a default configuration; you have to make a different configuration the default first.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just select US, click move up and then select Romanian Legacy, it will have the remove option enabled.

Comment: I tried and it does not work... It still does not have remove option enabled.

Comment: @Daniel can you attach the screenshot of your options after trying the above method.

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBV41.jpg) @Anurag Thakur

Comment: I did it under these comments.